# Getting json file using JSON.parse(chunk) returns Syntax Error on Lambda

Tags: javascript, json, aws-lambda, https

I am attempting to send an HTTPS request to get a JSON file stored on AWS S3 using a Lambda function. It works fine on localhost and Lambda test, but when the Lambda function is actually called, it returns this error, "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0".

Is this because returned chunk is a buffer starting with "<"? Then, why does it work on localhost?

I have tried testing with exactly the same event JSON, but nothing seems to work. The part of the code where it is returning an error is below.

```
const jsonURL = `https://XXXX.cloudfront.net/${event.detail.recording_s3_key_prefix}/events/recording-ended.json`

https.get(jsonURL, res => {
    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        // getting the json contents
        const json = JSON.parse(chunk)
        const duration = moment.utc(json.media.hls.duration_ms).format("HH:mm:ss");

        // do a mongoose Model.find...
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

this could caused by http response error (like 404(Not Found)).
you should check the response like below

```
const jsonURL = `https://XXXX.cloudfront.net/${event.detail.recording_s3_key_prefix}/events/recording-ended.json`

https.get(jsonURL, res => {
    res.on('data', (chunk) => {

        console.log(chunk)  // check(json or not) the 'chunk' before parse 

        // getting the json contents
        const json = JSON.parse(chunk)
        const duration = moment.utc(json.media.hls.duration_ms).format("HH:mm:ss");

        // do a mongoose Model.find...
        });
    })
```

if it is json, try copy&paste the logs to json validator site(like [devutils.org](https://devutils.org/)) or paste here for more help.